# Is there a way to monitor mounted files (in docker container) by inotifywait?

Tags: bash, docker, inotifywait

I'm Trying to print all the files in some directory when they are changed. 
**for example:** 
I want to print all the files that changed under **Lupidon** directory

```
├───Bills
├───Mortgage
├───Zeus
│   ├───Cronus
│   └───Lupidon
```

I'm using the next bash command which I found at **stack overflow**:

```
inotifywait -qrm --event modify --format %f /Zeus/Lupidon
```

This is working for every file that I added to the **Lupidon** directory,
but when if Lupidon will be directory inside docker container which persist data from the host (by volume), When files changed from the host, the container show this files changed but nothing printed

Am I doing something wrong? there is other way to get this functionality by other tool?

Comment: Where is the volume mounted from? If it is a remote filesystem e.g. mounted via network - which may also be the case when running `docker` on Windows or macOS since the directory lives on filesystem of the host OS and not in the Linux VM `docker` is actually running in. In that case the Linux kernel can not track changes on the _remote_ filesystem^^